# How can I force ajax to refresh its data?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I've got a website, and which shows a date certified, when the user checks a box. 
On click of the box, the call is made, and the data is updated in the database.
The site then steps through some ajax code and displays the date certified. The problem is that the date isn't refreshed instantly until you re-enter the page, and the call is made again to the database.

So if I certified yesterday, and then come in and re-certify today, the date shown is yesterday, until I re-enter the application (upon which it'll show today's date).

The certify checkbox is located in a jsp file using the following:

```
<p>
        <html:checkbox name="dBean" property="certified" value="true" styleClass="certify"/> 
        I certify that the information above is accurate to the best of my knowledge.
</p>
```

After the checkbox is clicked, the following in called in the ajax to update boolean values:

```
function setCertifDataStore(section, isCertified){
   if(section == "s1")
       $('#content').data("isS1Certified", isCertified);
   if(section == "s2"){
       $('#content').data("isS2Certified", isCertified);
       alert('S2 update');
   }
}
```

To update the date, I figured I could do the following inside of the ajax:

```
if(section == "s2"){
    $('#content').data("isS2Certified", isCertified);
    alert('fi update');
    $('#content').data("S2CertDate", S2CertDate);
}
```

But that causes the application to freeze/hang. 
Is this the right way in ajax to refresh the data?

It's a java website, springs framework, with ajax and jquery if that helps.

Comment: Are you sure that you perform the ajax call (which updates the browser value) when the database update is fully completed on the server side ?

Comment: @RoniTovi. I don't believe that I'm doing that. Can you tell me how I can make that call?

Comment: you should paste some of your code here

Comment: also put the event handler code. we need to see what you're exactly doing on click of that checkbox.

Comment: Hi @RoniTovi, added the code in ajax where it seems to be handled, and I tried to update the date there, but the application ended up freezing.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do actions with the response of ajax request

```
$.ajax({
 //connection stuff
}).done(function(response) {
  updateDate(response.date);
});

function updateDate(date){
  //stuff for update the date
}
```

More info about ajax request with jquery in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/